# Separating range into intervals and outputting it into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, range

I'm trying to separate a range of 1200 values into 10 different intervals and find the number of values in each interval. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
load('Data.mat')
% % Train=Data(i_tr,:);
l_train=height(Train);
Sdrr=Train.SDRR;

R_SDRR=range(Sdrr);
min_SDRR=min(Sdrr);
max_SDRR=max(Sdrr);
intervals=10;
int_SDRR=R_SDRR/intervals;
data=zeros(intervals,1);

for j=1:l_train
    for k=1:intervals-1
        if min_SDRR+(k-1)*int_SDRR<=Sdrr(j)<min_SDRR+(k)*int_SDRR
            data(k)=data(k)+1;
        else

        end
    end
end
```

The values I am getting seem to be cumulative rather than separate in the output array i.e. 238,519,745...(this has to be wrong because the total number of inputs are 1200)

Comment: Can you include a few values in Data.mat ?

Comment: sure data.mat is a 1613*4 table which is cut down to a 1200*4 table with values like ID: 1,2,3,4   Pwave:1 0 0 0 1 1 1 SDRR: 0.0725 0.04047 0.10232 diagnosis: 0 0 0 1 1 1 etc

Comment: and i extract the SDRR of the table

Comment: See my answer below and let me know if that's not what you're trying to do: divide your 1200x4 into 10 different intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce what I think you're trying to do.

I created some random data that matches your size:

```
X = rand(1613,4);
X = X(1:1200,:);
```

Now `X` is 1200-by-4.

You want to use 10 intervals:

```
n_interval = 10;
```

Need to calculate how many values (`len_interval`) you will have in each interval:

```
len_X = size(X,1);

% using round() in case len_X/n_interval is not an int
len_interval = round(len_X/n_interval);
```

Then go through each interval and store the values in `interval` cell.

```
interval = {};
for i = 1:n_interval
    if i==n_interval % last interval
        interval{i} = X((i-1)*len_interval+1:len_X);
    else
        interval{i} = X((i-1)*len_interval+1:i*len_interval);
    end
end
```

Comment: it seems I haven't made what i want to do clear enough I apologize. I want to sum the number of values between the 1st tenth of the range (i.e between 0 and 0.04) and the 2nd tenth and so on. This solution cuts the 1200 values into the 1st 120 values and 2nd 120 values etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you want to distribute `N = 1200` values into `intervals` buckets.

```
intervals = 10;
min_range = 0;
max_range = 100;

data = rand(1200, 1) * max_range; % 1200 random numbers between 0 and 100

intervals_size = (max_range - min_range) / intervals; % Size of each interval
```

Now we can calculate the "interval number" in which a given data falls by subtracting the minimum value from the data, dividing the result by the interval size, and `floor`ing the result.

```
interval_num = floor((data - min_range) / intervals_size);
```

Then, it's just a question of counting how many of each number exist. You can do it a whole bunch of ways:

Ex. 1:

```
intervals_count = zeros(intervals, 1);
for ii = 1:intervals
    intervals_count = sum(interval_num == ii - 1)
end
```

Ex. 2:

```
intervals_count = zeros(intervals, 1);
for ii = 1:length(interval_num)
    group_num = interval_num(ii) + 1;
    intervals_count(group_num) = intervals_count(group_num) + 1;
end
```

Ex. 3: If you have Matlab >= 2019a, simply use the [`groupcounts()` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.groupcounts.html)

```
[intervals_count, interval_num2] = groupcounts(interval_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

i used the and operator and changed the order of the for loops and it fixed my answer

```
R_SDRR=range(Sdrr);
min_SDRR=min(Sdrr);
max_SDRR=max(Sdrr);
intervals=10;
int_SDRR=R_SDRR/intervals;
data=zeros(intervals,1);
int_array = zeros(10,1);


for j=1:intervals
    for k=1:l_train
     if Sdrr(k)<min_SDRR+(j)*int_SDRR && Sdrr(k)>=min_SDRR+(j-1)*int_SDRR
int_array(j)= int_array(j)+1;     
     end
    end
end
```